# Materialize css all tabs coming together below each other, but working properly after refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, materialize

I use materialize css tabs and it loads all the divs, one below the other on the first load.

If i refresh the page, it starts behaving properly.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col s12">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test1">Test 1</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test2">Test 2</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s3 disabled"><a href="#test3">Disabled Tab</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test4">Test 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="test1" class="col s12">Test 1</div>
<div id="test2" class="col s12">Test 2</div>
<div id="test3" class="col s12">Test 3</div>
<div id="test4" class="col s12">Test 4</div>
```

This just gives me the snippet below on the first load / server restart:

[snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9Yao.png)

Now, if i refresh the page. It works as expected.

I imported all the required js(jquery and materialize) and css and I also added the initialization for tabs.

```
$(window).on("load", function () {
    $('ul.tabs').tabs();
  });
```

i have tried

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('ul.tabs').tabs();
      });
```

The issue still persists.

Anyone know the solution to this?

I am facing too many issues like these with materialize.

Also, I use react. If that makes any difference.

Using react-materialize, I face the below issue.

```
<Tabs className='tab purple darken-4'>
                <div className="container">
                    <Tab title="All">1</Tab>
                    <Tab title="Ongoing" active>2</Tab>
                    <Tab title="Successful">3</Tab>
                    <Tab title="Failed/Warning">4</Tab>
            </div>
 </Tabs>
```

[React issue on adding divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKNzb.png)

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Can you provide a picture with the issue?

Comment: added snippet in question

Comment: Check the order of script loading in the developer tools.Both before and after refreshing.

Comment: Mixing react and jQuery is not a good idea. I suggest you to consider using a react version of material-ui.

Comment: @HemaNandagopal 
The files are loading in the correct order.
1. jQuery
2. Materialize.js
3. then  react bundle js

Comment: @bennygenel Using react-materialize is very restrictive. I cannot wrap my tabs in divs. It just breaks

Comment: What do you mean by restrictive? What do you mean by breaks?

Comment: @bennygenel Please see edit. Tabs just disappear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use Tabs component; react-materialize get the child components and renders them accordingly. Since you are wrapping all components with a single div the render breaks.

You can try doing something like this;

```
<div className="container">
    <Tabs className='tab purple darken-4'>
        <Tab title="All">1</Tab>
        <Tab title="Ongoing" active>2</Tab>
        <Tab title="Successful">3</Tab>
        <Tab title="Failed/Warning">4</Tab>       
    </Tabs>
</div>
```

**OR**

```
<Tabs className='tab purple darken-4'>
    <Tab title="All">
        <div className="container">
            1
        </div>
    </Tab>
    <Tab title="Ongoing">
        <div className="container">
            2
        </div>
    </Tab>
    <Tab title="Successful">
        <div className="container">
            3
        </div>
    </Tab>
    <Tab title="Failed/Warning">
        <div className="container">
            4
        </div>
    </Tab>    
</Tabs>
```

If you like to change the apperiance of the Tabs or a single Tab component you can use `className` prop for them too.

Comment: Thanks!. This solved one problem, but gave another.
The underline for active is not coming on the first item.
If go to the second tab and come back to the first tab, it appears

Comment: you need to set the initial active tab I think. Check the docs for more info.